# Searching for numbers in each row

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"T1":[1, 7, 1, 6],
                   "T2": [7, 8, 9, 2],
                   "T3": [8, 6, 6, 6],
                   "T4": [3, 3, 3, 8]
                   "T5": [9, 1, 2, 7]
}
)

print(df1)

    T1      T2     T3      T4   T5
0   1       7       8      3    9
1   7       8       6      3    1
2   1       9       6      3    2
3   6       2       6      8    7

 Cond1={ 1,8,3 }
 Cond2 ={ 7,8,6 }

   T1      T2     T3      T4   T5  Cond1   Cond2
0   1       7       8      3    9    T       F
1   7       8       6      3    1    T       T
2   1       9       6      3    2    F       F
3   6       2       6      8    7    F       T
```

I'm looking for any row that contain the numbers [1 , 8 ,3 ] which would be row '0' and '1'. I would like to change the numbers I'm searching for to be [7,8,6] which would be row '1' and '3' . Then creating another column that states it's true or false for condition 1 and condition 2 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for **different** numbers, you can use set operations:

```
target = {1,8,3}
df1.index[[target.issubset(s) for s in df1.agg(set, axis=1)]]
```

Output: `Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')`

If you want the rows:

```
target = {1,8,3}
df1[[target.issubset(s) for s in df1.agg(set, axis=1)]]
```

Output:

```
   T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
0   1   7   8   3   9
1   7   8   6   3   1
```

Comment: Thank You. This was very helpful. In the case that I need a case statement that checks if a target is in the subset and creates a true or false column next to T5. How would I approach that?

Comment: `df1['new'] = [target.issubset(s) for s in df1.agg(set, axis=1)]`